# latch(used for awaiting async response) freezes the WebView (and the UI)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous

I have an app that displays a webview on the whole layout. Sometimes I need to call an async method, that async operation is done by a 3-party sdk, and then I wait for it for a while until I get the response to a designated listener. I have solved it with a latch - once the response is received in the listener, I countDown the latch and then the initiating method can continue with this response. 
Unfortunately, when I do this, the WebView is stuck. I imagined the native UI would be stuck , but I didn't expect the webview to get frozen as well.
How can that be overcome?

To make it clearer, here is an example. **I need the ajaxFunc to wait until MyAsyncListener gets a certain response, and then return this exact response.**

part of JS I inject to the webview :

```
var response = jsHandler.ajaxFunc(request.data);
```

I have a variable global variable called `response`.

```
public class JavaScriptInterface
{
     @JavascriptInterface
     public String ajaxFunc(String data)
     {
         return MyUtils.handleData( data );
     }
}
```

the handleData method :

```
 public String handleData( String data )
 {
     SomeClass.startAsyncRequest(); // starts the async request, response is to come at the listener's callbacks .

     latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
     try {
         latch.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }
     catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return response;
   }
```

now, once the `handleData` function calls a function, that does something asynchronously, the async function then returns some answer inside some Listener :

```
myAsyncListener = new MyAsyncListener() {
    @Override
        public Response handleEvent(CustomEvent event) {
            //Now I need to return this 'event' back to the handData/ajaxFunc function <-- 

            response = event.getName();
            latch.countDown();

        }
    });
```

Comment: "I need the ajaxFunc to wait..."  Why?

Comment: cause I have this line in the javascript :
`var response = jsHandler.ajaxFunc(request.data);`

Comment: in your code example, which one is the 3rd party call?

Comment: and, as i said in my answer, the webview freezes *because* you are making it wait with a latch

Answer (score 4):

> I need the ajaxFunc to wait until MyAsyncListener gets a certain response, and then return this exact response.

Since you are dispatching an async request, you shouldn't expect the response to arrive in the same method call you made to start the async code. If you do this, the caller thread will block until the async response arrives, that is, it won't be async at all.

You can redesign your code to something like this:

```java
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void ajaxFunc(String data) {
        // draw a waiting animation or something
        MyUtils.handleData(data);
    }
}
```

```java
public void handleData(String data) {
    SomeClass.startAsyncRequest();
}
```

```java
myAsyncListener = new MyAsyncListener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(CustomEvent event) {
        // Do what you need to do
        // (update UI, call javascript etc.).
        //
        // Mind the thread that will execute this callback
        // to prevent multithreading issues.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have put `CountDownLatch` inside your code which will cause blocking of your main thread. Thats the reason of lag on UI.

For better you should show some `ProgressDialog` before doing main work of Async task which generally written in `doInBackground()` method of Async task and hide it after completing your task, Async provide `onPostExecute()` method for that purpose.

If you need to put some timeout like your `CountDownLatch` is doing, you can write timer in `doInBackground()` of Async. That timer will stop your current Async will allotted time is elapsed.

Update, you could use EventBus for your purpose -

EventBus works on Publish/Subscribe pattern. You can subscribe in `Activity` and publish result from `JavaScriptInterface`.

Add it in gradle using -

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

In your `Activity` start subscribing, generally subscriptions done in `onCreate` method of `Activity` -

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

Also remove subscriptions in `onDestroy` method of `Activity` or if your work is done.

```
EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
```

To listen subscription use below code in your `Activity` -

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
     public void onMessageEvent(MyMessageEvent event) {
     // Do your work after getting result from ajaxFunc method
 };
```

You just have to post message notification from your method now and remove `CountDown` latch from your code if it is not needed somewhere else.

```
myAsyncListener = new MyAsyncListener() {
    @Override
        public Response handleEvent(CustomEvent event){ 
        response = event.getName();
        // Create object of message and post it
        final MyMessageEvent msgEvent = new MessageEvent(response);
        EventBus.getDefault().post(msgEvent);
    }
});
```

MyMessageEvent.class

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

public class MyMessageEvent {

    private String mMessage;

    public MyMessageEvent(@NonNull final String message) {
        mMessage = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return mMessage;
    }

}
```

Comment: the loading/progress dialog is shown (well, should be shown) within the WebView once I get to the JavacriptInterface method, and that is crucial that I don't use a native progress dialog.
Regarding the timer, yes I have to use a certain timer, but from what I understand you're saying that I should use AsyncTask class? Unfortunately I don't understand though how can I use it here? The async operation is happening in a 3-party sdk, and only returns a reponse to this Listener that I have..

Comment: So either make your webview disabled before starting background work.

Comment: and how would that help? Would the webview not be stuck even despite the use of the latch?

Comment: but the javaInterface method `handleData` is called from Javascript , and 
`AnyCallBackListener` is native android interface.. that means I can't pass it from the javascript

Comment: Oh yes, sorry then you can use EventBus for that purpose instead of interface. Your Activity will be subscriber and you have to publish message/notification after getting response from ajax function. EventBus works on pub/sub pattern. For more check this - https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand.. Will that help me make the `ajaxFunc` wait for the response for the listener before returning value?

Comment: also, once the reponse is back to ajaxFunc, will it be in some sort of anonymous class that will prevent me from returning the value from the main method(ajaxFunc itself, that is)

Comment: yes but apparently the javascript that was injected to the webview was to blame, since JS is single thread and it was stuck there waiting for a response from ajacFunc..

Comment: @BVtp make ajaxFunc void and don't wait for response there, EventBus will notify when task is done.

Comment: the thing is that the server side is waiting for that response, it needs it to know what to do.. so I guess I'd have to make changes there too

Answer (score 0):

### Android Thread Model

As [JCIP](http://jcip.net/) introduced, many UI framework is single threaded. They use thread confinement to avoid deadlock and integrity of data. Android also use this thread model.

> By default, all components of the same application run in the same process and thread (called the “main” thread).

So if you wait on main thread by using lacth, the UI will be not updated or response your action.

### Background Task

But sometimes, we want to perform some long time task like using network to download something and read from db. In order to make UI responsive, we should perform those jobs in another thread (Notice: not in the Service, which default still run on the main thread).

#### Java Way

So you may use `thread` or `executor`to fetch your data, then read data back into main thread like following method when some event happens:

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
```

#### Android Way

Or you may use Android native `AsyncTask` which is conveinent. 
For example, when you want to check the username/password of user, you have to connect to your server to verify it. In such scenario, you can put the request and verification process into a AsyncTask and the UI thread can make some animation when there is no response. Following is some code:

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mName;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String name, String password) {
        mName = name;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    // backgroud thread
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // network access.

        for (String credential : CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mName)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // register the new account here.
        return true;
    }

    // UI thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            // start next
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Drawer.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString( R.string.error_incorrect_password ));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

#### Ref:

- [My blog related with Android Thread](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2016/08/android-thread.html)

Comment: I found out that the problem isn't in Android. it's in the JavaScript I load to the webview : `var response = jsHandler.ajaxFunc(request.data);`
because JS is single-threaded this line makes the webview freeze. (At least from what I understand and have read)..

Comment: @BVtp I am glad you solved your problem. Sorry didn't understand your question fully.